# Setting up a staging server workflow (for a relative beginner)

Tags: workflows

I'm working on a Drupal 6 project and would like to set up a simple staging/live server workflow.

I know Drupal pretty well, including the Features module, and am relatively familiar with Git; as for the server itself, I've only got FTP access. I'd be interested in hearing possible ssh-based solutions too, though.

Can anyone recommend a suitable workflow, or suggest what I should consider if I have to develop my own workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for, that being your production server being remote, you might want to consider installing a devdesktop from acquia.com if you're using a Windoze or mac development system.  Then you can use features and/or deploy to move you changes to the production system via ftp.

If you're using a *nix development box I'd install Drupal directly and still use features and/or deploy to move things.

Worth a try -

Comment: Thanks, bobmct, that's pretty much what I'm doing already so I'll stick with my current workflow :)